# Java/Selenium - how to eliminate white space before using assertequals

Tags: java, selenium

I have a dropdown with multiple options. I want to get all of the available options in the dropdown, and then compare it with a list of values that I expect to be in there.

Here is the HTML for the dropdown.

```
<select id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dq14_response" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$dq14$response">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<option value="253">DEP900</option>
<option value="252">DEP800</option>
<option value="251">DEP700</option>
<option value="250">DEP600</option>
<option value="248">DEP400</option>
<option value="247">DEP300</option>
<option value="246">DEP200</option>
<option value="245">DEP100</option>
<option value="249">DEP500</option>
<option value="254">DEP1000</option>
</select>
```

I am using the below code to get all the text values in the dropdown, and then compare with what I expect the values to be.

```
List<Element> options = driver.getElements(AppObjects.Basic1_Dropdown);
        for(Element opt : options){
            String actualtext = opt.getText();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List listA = Arrays.asList("Please Select...", "DEP900", "DEP800", "DEP700", "DEP600", "DEP400", "DEP300", "DEP200", "DEP100", "DEP500", "DEP1000");            
        Assert.assertEquals(actualtext, listA);
        }
```

This test fails for me because the returned text is on a different line. I get an error saying the actual text is (without the dashes):

```
- DEP900
- DEP800
- DEP700
- DEP600
- DEP400
- DEP300
- DEP200
- DEP100
- DEP500
- DEP1000
```

but the expected text was DEP900, DEP800, DEP700, DEP600, DEP400, DEP300, DEP200, DEP100, DEP500, DEP1000

How can I change my code so that the expected text matches the actual text. Do I need to remove spaces from the actualtext variable, or add them to listA?

I've also tried changing list A to below. I'm still not getting the actual and expected text to match, even though the actual and expected text in my error message look the same.

```
List listA = Arrays.asList("Please Select... \nDEP900 \nDEP800 \nDEP700 \nDEP600 \nDEP400 \nDEP300 \nDEP200 \nDEP100 \nDEP500 \nDEP1000");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `actualtext` which is a String with `listA` which is a List. This should not work.
Instead create a 2nd list which should contain all the text values of the Elements in the options list. You should compare this list with listA.

```
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("Please Select...", "DEP900", "DEP800", "DEP700", "DEP600", "DEP400", "DEP300", "DEP200", "DEP100", "DEP500", "DEP1000");
List<String> listB = new ArrayList();
List<Element> options = driver.getElements(AppObjects.Basic1_Dropdown);
for(Element opt : options){
   String actualtext = opt.getText();
   listB.add(actualtext);
}
Assert.assertEquals(listB, listA);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is what finally made it work for me. White space was causing a lot of my problems.

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
    listA.add("Please Select...\nDEP900\nDEP800\nDEP700\nDEP600\nDEP400\nDEP300\nDEP200\nDEP100\nDEP500\nDEP1000");
    System.out.println(listA);
    List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Element> options = driver.getElements(AppObjects.Basic1_Dropdown);

    for(Element opt : options){
       String actualtext = opt.getText();
       listB.add(actualtext);
       System.out.println(listB);   
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(listB, listA);
```